# Selenium webdriver doesn't show error about noutfounding element

Tags: selenium, webdriver, autotest

I try to find text on the page driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Some text')]"));

I know that text not displayed in the page. But system accepts test as Successed.

Why System doesn't show Error about NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use the result of `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Some text')]"));` like not clicking it `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Some text')]")).click();` or something else.
Calling the `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'Some text')]"));` returns `null` but you do not assert or verify the result in any way.